# Using Viber bot API to broadcast messages, all the iphones can not show the images of the rich messages

Tags: iphone, viber-bot, viber-api, python-responses

Using the Viber API and especially the "broadcast" feature (https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#broadcast-message) all the rich messages on Android are sent and shown normally, although in all iphones that I have tested, the image of the rich message is not showing at all.

Using Python

```
url = 'https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/broadcast_message'
        headers = {
            'X-Viber-Auth-Token': viber_token
        }
data = json.dumps(_broadcast_template, indent=4)
broadcast_response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```